# Sickbeard not auto starting after reboot

Tags: debian, debian-jessie

I've installed Sickbeard on Debian everything works except the auto starting when the server reboots.

I've followed this guide http://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-sickbeard-on-ubuntu/

Someone who could help me out on this?

Comment: Debian Jessie ships with systemd. Using the old `init.d`-style scripts is no longer the best way. Just to make sure: You did successfully complete step 5 of this guide, right?

Comment: yes I did. No errors except when I do sudo service sickbeard restart then it doesn't work.